# Another white wildflower growing in Serbia - what is it?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

For some reason I didn't mow this white wildflower, but I could, unless you tell me it is some relatively useful plant. Grows in partial shade. Here are photos:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excellent plant ID photos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bulge behind the flower (I forget the technical name) makes it look like some kind of campion. Take a look at *Silene latifolia* (white campion) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silene_latifolia).

Comment: bulge = capsule (in techno-speak)?

Comment: I think you are right - it is Silene latifolia. Still, let's wait if somebody has a different answer.

Comment: Definitely agree with this. From the closeup photo of the flower, you can see the deeply notched petals and that little "flower within a flower" formed by the fringe on the petals at the opening of the floral tube.